# DUT Chrome App Automated Testing on Chromebook using Autotest and Chromedriver

Tags: testing, automation, google-chrome-app, chromium, selenium-chromedriver

My company has a Chrome App I have been running automated testing on using Selenium and Chromedriver on Mac and Windows. They recently asked if it would be possible to get an automation setup going on an actual ChromeBook. I had initially looked into this ~three years ago, but the Autotest and Chromedriver integration into the Chromium test builds wasn't in place then.

From all of the research I have done thus far it appears to be possible. However there really seems to be a lack of instructions and documentation for Autotest, test_that (Autotest's Chromium script), and how to get it hooked to the DUT (Device Under Test). Chromedriver is built into the Chromium test images (and I have located it on my own Chromium test build) and supposedly can be launched using Autotest on the DUT from a host chronos root.

If anyone knows of a good resource or has first hand knowledge please let me know. I'll post links to all the Chromium resources I have been reading.

Is there a decent resource for autotest and test_that script usage within a Chromium test build?

Many thanks!

```
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/third_party/autotest/
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started/chromeos
```

Comment: Adding more links to resources I have been reading.

http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/testing/test-code-labs/autotest-client-tests
https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/testing/autotest-developer-faq/setup-autotest-server
https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/testing/autotest-developer-faq
https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/testing/autotest-user-doc

Comment: Do you have a concrete question you need answered? This post seems more discussion based. Please review the how to ask for help on asking questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi. Did you find it out?